# Write a SSIS script task to get oauth2.0 bearer token from a Web API

Tags: c#, ssis, postman, bearer-token, script-task

I am trying to figure out a way to get oauth2.0 bearer token from the rest API.

So from Postman I can do a POST method for "https://helloworld.org:443/xyz/oauth2/token"

And in the body, I choose x-www-form-urlencoded and put grant_type as "password" and put the values for my username and password. This gives me a token which is a bearer token and I use this to get data out of the API endpoints.

I want to do this in SSIS and I cannot use the web service task because this API is a REST API and not SOAP so it  does not have any services that returns the token back. I have to do it in a script task. When I run the script task I get this error "Error occurred while fetching the bearer token: Not Found"

Below is my script task code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace ST_9e6c1ec9747f4bca8db831645eddf61d
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            // Variables to store the credentials and API endpoint
            string username = "sadao002";
            string password = "dsf83837%%";
            string apiEndpoint = "https://helloworld.org:443/xyz/oauth2/token";

            // Create an HttpClient instance
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Set the base address of the API
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiEndpoint);

                // Define the content (username, password, and grant_type) to be sent as form data
                var formData = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "username", username },
                    { "password", password },
                    { "grant_type", "password" }
                };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);

                // Set the content type header
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                // Send the request and receive the response
                var response = client.PostAsync("/token", content).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Read the response content as string
                    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    // Assuming the response contains a JSON object with an "access_token" field for the bearer token
                    // You can parse the JSON manually, or using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer if you're using .NET Core 3.0 or later.
                    // For simplicity, we'll just look for "access_token":"value" pattern.
                    int tokenIndex = responseBody.IndexOf("\"access_token\":\"");
                    if (tokenIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        tokenIndex += "\"access_token\":\"".Length;
                        int tokenEndIndex = responseBody.IndexOf("\"", tokenIndex);
                        string bearerToken = responseBody.Substring(tokenIndex, tokenEndIndex - tokenIndex);

                        // Now you have the bearer token, you can use it for your subsequent requests.
                        // For example, you can store it in a package variable or use it in the same script task.
                        MessageBox.Show("Bearer Token: " + bearerToken, "Token Fetched Successfully");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Unable to fetch bearer token. Response does not contain a valid token.", "Error");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error occurred while fetching the bearer token: " + response.ReasonPhrase, "Error");
                }
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        public enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Do i have to include the port number in the apiEndpoint?
2. In this line, is it adding "/token" to the call?

   ```
    var response = client.PostAsync("/token", content).Result
   ```

   Thanks for any help.

I tried the above code and a lot of googling and research.

Comment: Hi there, did you manage to figure out a solution for this?